# Installing two grails app on Tomcat causes exception

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, grails

I need to have Tomcat with two grails applications installed. 
Both applications should be using 8080 as follows:
localhost:8080/app1
localhost:8080/app2

I tried to put my two war files in ***webapps*** folder and then upload the server.
While server was uploading, I got this exception in my catalina.out log file:

> Apr 23, 2014 1:27:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>  Apr 23, 2014
>   1:27:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>  SEVERE: Failed
>   to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-bio-8080"]
>  ***java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>   :8080***
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>      at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

Therefore, I need to know what is the best practice to upload tomcat with two grails apps.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: is there any other instance of tomcat running?

Comment: Strange, i am not sure but you try this `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`. see if any process is running on this port. Try killing it and restart your tomcat.

Comment: It gave me this line:
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      2743/java

Comment: i suspect a tomcat running in the background. using `ps -ef | grep tomcat` will give you the process_id for process. use `kill -9 <process_id>` or `killall java` and then restart tomcat.

Comment: I tried to make it.
By running this command I got only one process running and I killed it.

Comment: ....
By running this command I got only one process running and I killed it.
I've upload the tomcat and its not running well, simply it just not running.
I think that maybe I need to configure something in the tomcat, but I don't know what.

Notice that when I'm uploading the server with the first app it runs fine, but when i'm adding the second one i'm getting the exception above.

Comment: This may sound really dumb but are you running an IDE that may be using the port 8080 while trying to run tomcat and deploy WAR files?

Answer (score 0):

How were these war files generated? With `grails war`?

I am a frequent deployer of Grails apps on Tomcat. Since there is no other service running on port 8080, it can be an issue caused by some trash in Tomcat. So, avoid to find yourself wasting time with the inner workings of Tomcat. If you can (your example is with localhost), a fast solution may be to try a fresh install of Tomcat. Otherwise, just try to clean the **work** and **temp** directories.

You also asked about the best practices... If you can stop Tomcat, do it, put the .war file in the **webapps** folder, and then, clean the **work** and **temp** directories before restarting it. Otherwise, just put the .war file in the webapps folder or send it through Tomcat Manager app (`http://localhost:8080/manager`). However, its common to get the PermGen space error after some redeploys. In this case, your only option will be to restart Tomcat.

As another tip, a better alternative to Tomcat Manager is PSI Probe (http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/), that provides both more information and control on your applications and on Tomcat.

Comment: The war files created using ***grails war*** as you said.
I've deleted the ***temp*** and ****work*** directories, and it's not working.

Comment: Did you try a fresh install (just unpack Tomcat zip/tar.gz)? Just for sake of knowing whether this is a Tomcat installation issue...